The signal arrives at BYBIT, but the position is not opened
I'm new to creating a script.I have a very simple code for a large number of ongoing purchases. The buy signal goes to bybit, but the deal does not open.
//@version=5
strategy("MS", overlay=true, pyramiding = 1000)

ema8 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema16 = ta.ema(close, 20)
longCondition = ta.crossover(ema8, ema16)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)

plot(ema8, color = color.green)
plot(ema16, color = color.red)


How do you set your alerts?

You must be aware at this point that Bybit has its own webhook and can receive trading signals directly from your tradingview setup.Most likely that's the reason it doesn't work
